# Optimizer statistics regarding sorting

Tags: database, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by, sql-execution-plan

I am a newbie in Oracle 11g and I have one question regarding the execution plan. I ran a query and even though there is no ORDER BY clause in the query, the statistics on the execution plan still shows that there are 6 sorts in memory. Can anyone please explain to me why this occurred? Below is the query and the statistics:

```
SQL> SELECT ZIP FROM NOZIPSORT WHERE ZIP BETWEEN '10000' AND '29999' AND rownum < 26;

25 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4176934817

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |    25 |   150 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| NOZIPSORT |    28 |   168 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<26)
   2 - filter("ZIP"<='29999' AND "ZIP">='10000')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        311  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         47  consistent gets
         38  physical reads
        520  redo size
        805  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        431  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          6  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         25  rows processed
```

Comment: Please note, the "Statistics" are not related to the "execution plan" itself - they are actual statistics from the execution of the query itself. Run it again, and you may see different statistics each time, even though the execution plan stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it will be the recursive calls that are doing some sorting - e.g. when the query is parsed, the data dictionary needs to be queried to check the table and column definitions, and some of these queries will involve DISTINCT or other operations that require sorting.